# Windows 7 process eating bandwith

Tags: windows-7, bandwidth

Our network person has told me that something running on my Windows 7 laptop is eating bandwith but the only thing he can give me is where it is going.

edge3.catalog.video.msn.com

Does anyone know what is using this url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably use an application like [Networx](http://www.softperfect.com/products/networx/) to find what's doing it. The 'Netstat' function maps local applications to remote addresses, tick the 'Resolve Addresses to Host Names' button.

Comment: Or use Sysinternals TcpView (http://live.sysinternals.com/Tcpview.exe) to see what process accesses that particular address.

Comment: @atzz I'll try that

Answer (score 0):

Not a programming question but its probably MSN messenger or some MSN tool that has been installed.

http://www.robtex.com/dns/edge3.catalog.video.msn.com.html#records

Answer (score 0):

Execute `netstat -b | more` on [a command line with admin rights](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/window-on-windows/?p=603). This will show you a list of all outgoing connections with process names. Now press space to page through the results to find the one connecting to edge3.catalog.video.msn.com.

Answer (score 0):

Or use sysinternals [TCPView tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx)